# How to Save and Restore the Iptables rule and configuration from file?

Tags: linux, networking

I want to save the current iptables configuration to a file and restore it from a file.
I have a lot of rules and modifying the rules really hard for me.
So, how can i do that?!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the configuration and rules, so you must save the current configuration to a file.
So step one is to save the rules configuration by typing the following commands:

```
$ sudo iptables-save > /root/my-iptables.rules
```

To restore it just use the command iptables-restore:

```
$ sudo iptables-restore < /root/my-iptables.rules
```

⚠️ When you changed the existing rules after saving the file, You should save it again or change the existing file and restore it from the file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out, is that you should already be writing IP tables rules to a file, and restoring them from that file at start up - otherwise you will lose all of the rules when the server reboots.

The standard commands to do this on Debian are:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

**DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE**

> If you make a change that breaks your networking, killing your access
> to the server, then you can only recover by walking to the computer's
> console, and logging in there to fix the problem.  If thats a Cloud
> server, or in a different city / country / continent you have a bigger
> problem.

The next issue that i want to cover, is if writing individual rules is hard, the config files just capture the same command that you would type into the terminal window. Using a configuration file does not reduce the complexity here.

Personally, I would use the existing file to help with the syntax (e.g. find something that already does something that i want to do), and then run that command manually in the shell, and verify that it does what i need it to do by testing the network connections carefully, and thoroughly.  I would then save rules, knowing that they are already working and tested.

If i messed up, a server reboot, using the management panel for the server would at least restore the previous IP table rules.